# Creating a Custom Post Type and Joining with Users

Tags: custom-post-types, user-registration, events

I'm really having a difficult time figuring this out conceptually. I'm trying to create a sort of management system for events/volunteering. Let's say I create a custom post type called events, for each of these post types I'd like a form to be tied to them (may have this form be built with gravity forms and have it manually in the theme template for the custom post page). When the user fills out the form, they become a user and register for the event (post type).

How do I set it up to tie each post id to a registration and when you look up the custom post types table you have a column that lists the amount of people signed up for that specific id? Is there also a way to limit the number of registrations to that event (custom post type id)? There are very few references for this.

Comment: You should create a custom post type (for example, name it `event`), and create a new user role (name it `participant`) mapped with that custom post type. And then use `wp_insert_user` with `role` set to `participant` to register an user under `event` post type.
To limit number of registrations, use `WP_User_Query` with `role` and `count_total`.
This is the basic idea. Hope you should be able to make something with this.

Comment: Thanks! I think I understand this! So when I map the user role with the post type you mean giving it capabilities based on the custom post type?

Comment: Yes, by defining `capability_type` and `capabilities` in `register_post_type`. You will need to set `map_meta_cap` to `true`.